# angular4-grid Systemjs Angular 4

Tags: angular

**npm install angular4-grid**

**Error =>: No provider for NgGrid!**

```
map: {
'angular4-grid': 'node_modules/angular4-grid/bundles'
}
packages: {
'angular4-grid': { main: 'NgGrid.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
}
```

Module

```
import { NgGridModule } from 'angular4-grid';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
   ...
    NgGridModule
   ...
  ]
  providers:[]
})
```

Comment: i also got issue while going with angular4-grid and followed the below link (https://github.com/ggmod/angular-5-data-table) and able to implement grid functionalities like pagination, sorting , filter etc.

Comment: which version of Angular cli are using?

Answer (score 1):

not sure, but try after upgrade "@angular/compiler-cli" version